# SharePoint Directories/Files

Tags: sharepoint

I have a need that for a given sharepoint site, which i have read access to, i need to find out all the list/count of subdirectories & files. The folders go down 3-4 levels.

I have gone through this website for some options - 
https://www.softvative.com/blog/2015/02/four-ways-to-get-report-of-sharepoint-folders-and-files-for-a-library/

Still not able to get a list, can anyone suggest a simple way to get that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following C# code for your reference.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013/sites/team"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPListCollection docLibraryColl = web.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);

        foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl)
        {                        
            Console.WriteLine("-------------LibraryName:" + list.Title + "--------------");
            //get all folders in the library
            SPListItemCollection oFolders = list.Folders;

            //get all files in the library
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();           
            query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
            var files=list.GetItems(query);

            Console.WriteLine("Folder Count:"+oFolders.Count+" | File Count:"+files.Count);                                                                          
        }                    
    }
}
```